# changelog error in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, hudson, cvs

I have installed Jenkins version `1.599` on windows and configured `Jenkins` with `cvs` and able to checkout from `cvs` by checking `Skip changelog` option. But after unchecking this option I am getting the following error on running the build:

> **cvs rlog -S -d06 Mar 2015 18:49:11 +0500<09 Mar 2015 14:54:14 +0500 ns 
>   cvs [rlog aborted]: premature end of value in /home/cvs/src/ns/stencils/statements/Attic/CheckTemplateUCPA.rtf,v revision 1.6**
>
> **FATAL**: Error while trying to run CVS rlog
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while trying to run CVS rlog
>
> at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs.executeRlog(AbstractCvs.java:691)
>
> at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs.access$100(AbstractCvs.java:80)
>
> at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs$2.invoke(AbstractCvs.java:663)
>
> at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs$2.invoke(AbstractCvs.java:660)
>
> at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:989)
>
> at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
>
> at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs.getRemoteLogForModule(AbstractCvs.java:660)
>
> at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs.calculateChangeLog(AbstractCvs.java:779)
>
> at hudson.scm.AbstractCvs.postCheckout(AbstractCvs.java:794)
>
> at hudson.scm.CVSSCM.checkout(CVSSCM.java:351)
>
> at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1270)
>
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
>
> at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>
> at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:531)
>
> at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1718)
>
> at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>
> at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
>
> at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)

My `CVS` Plugin version is `2.11`

My `cvs` version is `Concurrent Versions System (CVSNT) 2.0.51d (client/server)`

Any idea? Is there any way to use the `cvs` log command for polling and the tag command for tagging (rather than `rlog` and `rtag`) without downgrading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'premature end of value' message is generated by the CVS Server when it has trouble applying a diff between different versions of a file. Whilst not using rlog would work around this, the actual fix would be to resolve the issue on your CVS server.

Unfortunately Jenkins does not currently support using anything other than rlog for calculating changes and creating the changelog.